# ¿Porque no me devuelve el texto ganaste?

Tags: javascript

Escribí la función `esPremioMayor()` la está cual recibiendo dos arrays, el primero con los números sorteados y el segundo con los números que jugaste. La función debe devolver el texto "Ganaste" si y solo si los 6 números jugados son iguales a los números sorteados, no importa el orden en el que hayan salido, de lo contrario devolverá la frase "Seguí participando".

Este es el codigo que eh intentado:

```
function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados){ 
if( numerosSorteados == numerosJugados){ return "Ganaste" } 
else { return "Seguí participando" }

}
```

Comment: Buenas Kevin! te informo que las consultas del estilo `¿Cómo hago esto?`  no son bienvenidas en S.O.es. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te hagas una mejor idea de como va la cosa

Comment: Me devuelve error porque no ordeno bien los numeros pero no entiendo

Comment: function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados){
    if( numerosSorteados == numerosJugados){
        return "Ganaste"
    } else {
        return "Seguí participando"
    }

}

Comment: Perdonen ahora edite mi publicación, me pueden ayudar porfa

Comment: Agrega en donde declaras esta funcion, y como la estas llamando

Comment: Quedo a la espera de lo que dice Miguel, borrare los comentarios anteriores para simplificar la seccion. Por adelantado, si obtienes los numeros en un array y los guardas en esas variables, reordena el array con métodos como sort() para ordenarlos si es que asi lo necesitas, recuerda agregar el codigo completo de estas aprtes

Answer (score 1):

En el código que pones no estás comparando los elementos del arreglo sino sus direcciones en la memoria por eso no se cumple la condición, una posible solución sería la que te propongo

```
function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados)
{
   var cont = 0;

   numerosSorteados.Sort();
   numerosJugados.Sort();

   for(var i = 0; i<=5;i++)
   {
      if(numerosJugados[i] == numerosSorteados[i])
      {
          cont++;
      }
   }

   if(cont == 6)
   {
      return "Ganaste";
   }
   else
   {
      return "Sigue jugando";
   }
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es que se ordenan los dos arreglos para que cada elemento de ambos arreglos queden en la misma posición. Una vez que están ordenados, se hace un ciclo desde 0 hasta 5, que serían los 6 elementos del arreglo, y se va comparando el valor de ambos arreglos en la posición i, de ser iguales se incrementa la variable cont,
una vez que se sale del ciclo se verifica la variable cont, que de ser igual a seis significa que todos los números son iguales, en caso contrario pues no lo son.
Otra forma de hacerlo sería utilizando la intersección de la teoría de conjuntos, si deseas puedes investigar esto en internet

Comment: Muy buena respuesta! solo hay que corregir **.Sort()** la primeta **S** es con minuscula **.sort()**